# Keras input issue

Tags: python, keras

I'm struggling with very strange issue with Keras (version 1.2.0).
Here is my NN model:

```
model = Sequential()
lindata=302
model.add(Dense(lindata, input_dim=lindata, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(60,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='softplus'))  
model.add(Dense(loutdata, activation='softplus'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the input is a vector of 302 floats and I have 376 of them in the training sample. 
now, when I run model.fit(),I get error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn.py", line 142, in <module>
    model.fit(all_indata,all_outdata,nb_epoch=35, batch_size=4) # nb_epoch=65 - not enough
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 664, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1068, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 981, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 54, in standardize_input_data
    '...')
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 376 arrays: [array([[  1.25000000e+11],
       [  1.20000000e-09],
       [  0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00],
       [  ...
```

This is how I create my input:

```
for line in datasample:
    elems=line.split(",")
    indata=np.array([[float(elems[i])] for i in range(2,len(elems)-1)])
    all_indata.append(indata)
```

I've tried converting indata to numpy array using asarray etc, but nothing works! Do you have any suggestions? It is second day I'm looking for a solution...

Mariusz

Comment: Right now, `all_indata` is a Python list. What happens when you try `all_indata = np.array(all_indata)`?

Comment: when I do this, I get the following error message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn.py", line 142, in <module>
    model.fit(all_indata,all_outdata,nb_epoch=35, batch_size=4) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 664, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 981, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_1 to have shape (None, 302) but got array with shape (376, 1)`

Comment: What is allindata.shape?

Comment: this is the funny thing. Before   all_indata=np.array(all_indata), python says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'. That is OK. After it says: TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable. Why? np.array should not produce a tuple...

Comment: I'm getting another error now (produced by model.fit function): "ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 376 arrays:...". I don't understand at which point models is informed that there should be only one array in the training sample?

Comment: Several days ago I have found that my problem has nothing to do with keras. It was related to not very trivial logic bug which made one of the input arrays empty...

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your loop like:

```
for line in datasample:
elems=line.split(",")
indata= [[float(elems[i])] for i in range(2,len(elems)-1)]
all_indata.append(indata)
```

After the loop apply numpy trasformation

```
numpy.array(all_indata)
```